# Script to rename the default log folder (W3SVC) in IIS

Tags: powershell, iis

I need a script to rename the default log folder in IIS (`W3SVC`) into the name of the website. For every website:

```powershell
Import-Module WebAdministration
$LogPath = “D:\Logs\IIS”
foreach($site in (dir iis:\sites\*)){
    New-Item $LogPath\$($site.Name) -type directory
    Set-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\$($site.Name) -name logFile.directory -value “$LogPath\$($site.Name)”
}
```

Comment: Do not use curly _smart-quotes_ in code and replace them all with straight ones. Please explain waht is not working with the code you are showing. If you get error messages, add them to the question.

Comment: your PowerShell script is working well there is no issue. if you just want to replace the folder name with the site name then first you need to get the all iis site log folder and then replace it with the site name.