# how can I change IIS log files directory names

Tags: iis, iis-10, application-pool

How can I change the default logfiles directory name for all sites?

For example:

```yaml
%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\{{ site_name }}
```

Where `{{ site_name }}` is the website name (e.g. `www.example.com`).

Comment: Site ID in the default folder names is enough to distinguish the folders from each other.

Answer (score 0):

As Lex Li said, I don't think it is necessary to modify the IIS log folder name.

The numbers on the IIS log default folder correspond to the ID of each site in IIS. Open the IIS manager, double-click the Sites node, you can see the IDs of all sites.

You can also run the following command to return the ID of the site: `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd list site`.

If the **ID of the site is 1**, the corresponding log folder name is **W3SVC1**, and the **ID=2** corresponds to **W3SVC2**, etc.

Comment: thank you for answer,
i know about that ...
but when i want to connect [without log in]  to server, with file shareing, i need log in to server and find ID ..

Comment: Hi, this thread might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59176786/i-need-a-script-to-rename-the-default-log-folder-in-iis-w3svc-into-the-name-of

Comment: this i'm doing with manual, but NetCore apps logging state don't working after that

Comment: Do you mean you manually modified the name of the default log folder?

Comment: manually i can, but my services more than 130